# Quotation marks in VBA formula don't work

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this line of code in VBA and it doesn't work, I think it is because of the quotation marks.

The code is: `.Cells(linhaVazia, 11).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4;Apoio!Q5:R100;2;FALSE);"""")".`

I have tried changing the quotation marks in a lot of ways but still couldn't fix it.

Comment: is the last `.` a typo ?

Comment: The quotes look correct (they work for me) ... could it be something else?

Comment: `.Formula` requires comma between parameters, not semicolons.

Comment: ...or use `FormulaLocal` but that's less robust if you have users across different locales.

Comment: Use .Value instead of .Formula. It should resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Change your formula to the following:

```
.Cells(linhaVazia, 11).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4;Apoio!Q5:R100;2;FALSE);"""")"
```

Basically replacing `.Formula` with `.Value` solves the issue, the sting (ie. formula) is then inserted into `.Cells(linhaVAzia,11)`.

You could then use

```
.Cells(linhaVazia,11).Value = .Cells(linhaVazia,11).Value
```

to only show the result of the formula in the cell. A bit slow, but resolves the issue with quotation marks.

**Solution 2**

Change your formula to the following:

```
.Cells(linhaVazia, 11).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4,Apoio!Q5:R100,2,FALSE),"""")"
```

Where `;` are replaced with `,`.